# <sub> and <sup> not rendering on browser printout

Tags: html, printing, subscript

I have a HTML table of measurements, with one column containing the unit of the measurement and I need to print this table out.

I am using the subscript tag in order to display the units in the correct format, e.g. **m<sub>3</sub>** for meter cubed.

However when I print this table out, currently using Chrome, the output is **m3** (with a big 3).

Is there something I need to do to tell the browser about the subscript, some css media trick perhaps?

Any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using `@media print {}` in your css? That worked for me, so it might an issue on your side.

Comment: I don't currently have any css on the table to use `@media print {}` with. I simply have the `<sub>3</sub>` in the table cell.

Comment: Just try to put this in your print css:
`sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}`